# How to efficiently address circular dependencies between matrixes in R?

Tags: r, list, matrix, dependencies, circular-dependency

I come to R from XLS where I'm used to addressing this sort of "circular reference" problem. I wonder if there's a clean, efficient way to handle this sort of issue in R.

The image below best explains my question. The original code at the bottom generates 3 matrixes, which are then embedded in lists. Data currently flows sequentially "downstream" from one matrix to another. For example, `$Series_One$Reserve$Out` flows to `$Series_One$Class_A_current$In`, and `$Series_One$Class_A_current$Out` flows to `$Series_One$Class_A_prior_unpd$In`. The flow is sequentially downward. But now I'm trying to figure how to send data "upstream"; I would like to send the values in column `$Series_One$Class_A_prior_unpd$Post_FC_short` "upstream" to `$Series_One$Reserve$Due_Class_A` as shown in the upward pointing arrow in the image below. As noted, the values currently in `$Series_One$Reserve$Due_Class_A` are only placeholders. The image below is a nice depiction of the classic circular reference problem. I also post an image for the **SHORT CODE** example.

In R, how are these types of mutual, circular dependencies best resolved?

How I would solve this manually is (in referencing the original code below) to first set all `$Series_One$Reserve$Due_Class_A` cells to zeroes, see what the resulting values are in `$Series_One$Class_A_prior_unpd$Post_FC_short`, and then **manually** plop those "pro forma" `$Series_One$Class_A_prior_unpd$Post_FC_short` values back into `$Series_One$Reserve$Due_Class_A`. But my mind keeps flashing "circular reference" after years of XLS use.

Apologies for the long original code (**I edited this post with SHORT CODE example that also illustrates the same circular reference issue**).

[image]

[image]

**Short Code:**

```
masterList <- list(
  list1 = data.frame(
    Inflow = c(10,15,12),
    Cover_list1 = c(4,5,2),
    Cover_list2 = c(0,0,0)
    ),
  list2 = data.frame(
    Cover_list2 = c(4,2,6),
    Draw_list1 = c(0,0,0)
    )
)


circRef <- function(x) {
  output <- x
  for (i in seq_along(x)) {
    sublist <- x[[i]]
    if (i == 2) {
      sublist <- cbind(Inflow = output[[1]]$Outflow, sublist)
      sublist$Outflow <- sublist$Inflow - sublist$Cover_list2 + sublist$Draw_list1
    }
    else {
      sublist$Outflow <- sublist$Inflow - rowSums(as.matrix(sublist[, -(1)]))
    }
    output[[i]] <- sublist
  }
  return(output)
}

circRef(masterList)
```

**Original Code:**

```
fallFCSeries <- list(Series_One = c('Reserve','Class_A_current','Class_A_prior_unpd'))
CF <- c(6, 5, 600)
balance <- c(1000,1100,1200)
resAcct <- list(Series_One = list(Target = 0.02,Classes = c('A')))

fallFC <- function(nbr_rows) {
  bucket <- vector('list', length = 1)
  series_elements <- fallFCSeries[["Series_One"]]
  mat_list <- vector('list', length = 3)
  
  for (j in seq_along(series_elements)) {
    element <- series_elements[j]
    mat <- matrix(0, nbr_rows, 
                  if (element == "Reserve") {7} else {
                    if(grepl("unpd",element)){7} else {5}
                } 
    )
    if (element == "Reserve") {
      colnames(mat) <- c('In','Target','Top','Due_Class_A','Draw_Class_A','End_bal','Out')
    } else {
      if(!grepl("unpd",element)){
        colnames(mat) <- c('In','Due','FC_cover','Post_FC_short','Out')
      } else{
        colnames(mat) <- c('In','Due','FC_cover','Post_FC_short','RA_cover','Post_RA_short','Out')
      }
    }
   
    for (k in 1:nbr_rows) {
      Bal <- balance[k]
      seriesCF <- CF[k]
     
      if (j == 1) {
        mat[k, "In"] <- seriesCF} else {mat[k,"In"] <- bucket[[1]][[j - 1]][k, "Out"]}
      if (element == "Reserve") {
        mat[k,"Target"] <- round(Bal * resAcct[["Series_One"]]$Target,2)
        mat[k,"Top"] <- min(mat[k,"In"], (max(0, mat[k, "Target"])))
        mat[k,"Out"] <- mat[k,"In"]
        
        cumTops <- sum(mat[1:k,"Top"])
        due_val <- round(runif(1, min = 0, max = mat[k,"Target"]),2) # this is placeholder!!
        mat[k, paste0("Due_Class_", "A")] <- due_val
        cum_draws_lag <- if(k == 1){0} else {sum(mat[1:k-1, grepl("^Draw", colnames(mat))])}
        sumDraws <- sum(mat[k,1:5][grepl("^Draw", colnames(mat)[1:5])]) 
        draw <- min(due_val,cumTops - cum_draws_lag - sumDraws)
        mat[k, "Draw_Class_A"] <- draw
        cumDraws <- sum(mat[1:k,grepl("^Draw", colnames(mat))])
        mat[k, "End_bal"] <- cumTops - cumDraws
        mat[k,"Out"] <- mat[k,"In"] - mat[k,"Top"]
      }
      else{ # if element <> "Reserve"...
        if(grepl("unpd",element)){  
          extractClass <- sub("_prior.*", "", element)
          pattern <- paste0(extractClass,".*current")
          match_element <- which(grepl(pattern, names(bucket[[1]])))  
        }
        
        mat[k, "Due"] <- if(!grepl("unpd", element)){
          round(Bal * 0.50,2) 
        } else {sum(bucket[[1]][[match_element]][1:k,"Post_FC_short"])}
          
        mat[k, "FC_cover"] <- min(mat[k, "In"], mat[k, "Due"])
        mat[k, "Post_FC_short"] <- mat[k, "Due"] - mat[k, "FC_cover"]
          
        if(grepl("unpd",element)){
          mat[k, "RA_cover"] <- 0
          mat[k, "Post_RA_short"] <- 0
        }
        mat[k, "Out"] <- mat[k, "In"] - mat[k, "FC_cover"]
      }
    } 
    mat_list[[j]] <- mat
    names(mat_list) <- series_elements
    bucket[[1]] <- setNames(mat_list, series_elements)
    } 
  names(bucket) <- "Series_One"
  
return(bucket)
}

fallFC(3)
```

Comment: Cool. Perhaps by picking the output of `reactlog_write` for single unique anchestors? https://rstudio.github.io/reactlog/reference/reactlog_write.html

Comment: Just do it in a loop.  Many such systems will converge to a steady-state value if you just iterate the computation.  The hard part is figuring out if you've got one of those convergent ones, or one that doesn't converge, either oscillating or exploding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are solutions for the short code and original code examples, following what I say in the OP with "How I would solve this manually is..." and user2554330 suggestion to solve it with a loop. I'm open to any cleaner solutions, R has amazing tricks the deeper you dig.

Short code solution (note my comments # ADDED):

```
circRef <- function(x) {
  output <- x
  
  for (i in 1:2) { # ADDED
    for (j in seq_along(x)) {
      sublist <- x[[j]]
      if (j == 2) {
        sublist <- cbind(Inflow = output[[1]]$Outflow, sublist)
        if(i == 2){sublist$Draw_list1 <- stored_values} # ADDED
        sublist$Outflow <- sublist$Inflow - sublist$Cover_list2 + sublist$Draw_list1
      }
      else {
        if(i == 2){sublist$Cover_list2 <- stored_values} # ADDED
        sublist$Outflow <- sublist$Inflow - rowSums(as.matrix(sublist[, -(1)]))
      }
      output[[j]] <- sublist
      
      if(i==1){stored_values <<- (sublist$Inflow - sublist$Cover_list2) * 0.50} # ADDED
    }
  }
  return(output)
}

circRef(masterList)
```

Original code solution:

```
fallFC <- function(nbr_rows) {
  bucket <- vector('list', length = 1)
  series_elements <- fallFCSeries[["Series_One"]]
  mat_list <- vector('list', length = 3)
  
  # iterate twice: first time without reserve due amounts; second time with prior_unpd Pst_FC_short amounts
  for (iter in 1:2) { # ADDED
    for (j in seq_along(series_elements)) {
      element <- series_elements[j]
      mat <- matrix(0, nbr_rows, 
                    if (element == "Reserve") {7} else {
                      if(grepl("unpd",element)){7} else {5}
                    } 
      )
      if (element == "Reserve") {
        colnames(mat) <- c('In','Target','Top','Due_Class_A','Draw_Class_A','End_bal','Out')
      } else {
        if(!grepl("unpd",element)){
          colnames(mat) <- c('In','Due','FC_cover','Post_FC_short','Out')
        } else{
          colnames(mat) <- c('In','Due','FC_cover','Post_FC_short','RA_cover','Post_RA_short','Out')
        }
      }
      
      for (k in 1:nbr_rows) {
        Bal <- balance[k]
        seriesCF <- CF[k]
        
        if (j == 1) {
          mat[k, "In"] <- seriesCF} else {mat[k,"In"] <- bucket[[1]][[j - 1]][k, "Out"]}
        if (element == "Reserve") {
          mat[k,"Target"] <- round(Bal * resAcct[["Series_One"]]$Target,2)
          mat[k,"Top"] <- min(mat[k,"In"], (max(0, mat[k, "Target"])))
          mat[k,"Out"] <- mat[k,"In"]
          
          cumTops <- sum(mat[1:k,"Top"])
          
          # ADDED: set all values to 0 in the first iteration
          due_val <- if (iter == 1) {0} else {stored_values[k]}
          
          mat[k, paste0("Due_Class_", "A")] <- due_val
          cum_draws_lag <- if(k == 1){0} else {sum(mat[1:k-1, grepl("^Draw", colnames(mat))])}
          sumDraws <- sum(mat[k,1:5][grepl("^Draw", colnames(mat)[1:5])]) 
          draw <- min(due_val,cumTops - cum_draws_lag - sumDraws)
          mat[k, "Draw_Class_A"] <- draw
          cumDraws <- sum(mat[1:k,grepl("^Draw", colnames(mat))])
          mat[k, "End_bal"] <- cumTops - cumDraws
          mat[k,"Out"] <- mat[k,"In"] - mat[k,"Top"]
        }
        else{ # if element <> "Reserve"...
          if(grepl("unpd",element)){  
            extractClass <- sub("_prior.*", "", element)
            pattern <- paste0(extractClass,".*current")
            match_element <- which(grepl(pattern, names(bucket[[1]])))  
          }
          
          mat[k, "Due"] <- if(!grepl("unpd", element)){
            round(Bal * 0.50,2) 
          } else {sum(bucket[[1]][[match_element]][1:k,"Post_FC_short"])}
          
          mat[k, "FC_cover"] <- min(mat[k, "In"], mat[k, "Due"])
          mat[k, "Post_FC_short"] <- mat[k, "Due"] - mat[k, "FC_cover"]
          
          if(grepl("unpd",element)){
            mat[k, "RA_cover"] <- draw
            mat[k, "Post_RA_short"] <- mat[k,"Post_FC_short"] - mat[k,"RA_cover"]
          }
          mat[k, "Out"] <- mat[k, "In"] - mat[k, "FC_cover"]
        }
      } 
      mat_list[[j]] <- mat
      names(mat_list) <- series_elements
      bucket[[1]] <- setNames(mat_list, series_elements)
    } 
  names(bucket) <- "Series_One"
  
  stored_values <- bucket[[1]][["Class_A_prior_unpd"]][, "Post_FC_short"] # ADDED
  
  } # close iteration ADDED
  
  return(bucket)
}

fallFC(3)
```